# no sound in mp4 Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

I haven't been using Sony Vegas too much, but this has never happened to me before...
[image]

All my videos look like this.. I can playback no problem, but without sound. It's mp4.
What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do the videos actually have sound?  Are they using an audio codec that Vegas understands?  It appears that Vegas thinks there is no audio since no waveforms are displayed.

Comment: It's working already.. I had to reencode the videos with Handbrake. Don't know where the problem was..